# Syslog-NG Error when using TLS and p12 file

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

Updated my syslog-ng config to accept ssl certificates.  When debugging, I'm stuck at this error:

```
syslog-ng Error parsing afsocket, syntax error, unexpected LL_IDENTIFIER, expecting ')'

pkcs12-file(/etc/syslog-ng/certs/mycert.p12)
```

If it helps, the version of syslog I'm running is:

```
syslog-ng 3.5.6
Available-Modules: afamqp,confgen,afuser,afsocket-notls,tfgeoip,redis,cryptofuncs,basicfuncs,afprog,csvparser,afmongodb,syslogformat,afsocket-tls,linux-kmsg-format,afsocket,json-plugin,affile,afsmtp,dbparser,system-source,afstomp,afsql
```

My guess, right now, is that there is a module I am missing.  Still looking into the error, however.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

v3.5.6 is really old, `pkcs12-file()` is only available in newer versions (>= 3.12.1).

Comment: I upgrade to version 3.16.  I noticed something strange recently.  Even though I'm specifying a port (3514), transport (tls), and ip (0.0.0.0) ... I noticed netstat -tulpn doesn't report that port 3514 is open.  Or receiving any traffic.

Comment: Did you reference the source in any log paths?